# with shared storage, how is the waiting mechanism for slave broker?

Tags: activemq-classic, master-slave

With NFS as the shared storage,  deployment of Master/slave is as following:

[image]

when starting, Broker1 first grab the lock in NFS, and Broker2 shows log info as following:

2012-08-27 11:38:36,245 | INFO  | Database /usr/local/wxcTest/mnt/amqDir/lock is locked... waiting 10 seconds for the database to be unlocked. Reason: java.io.IOException: File '/usr/local/wxcTest/mnt/amqDir/lock' could not be locked. | org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.MessageDatabase | main

I wonder it is normal?

and further, how is like the general mechanism when Broker2 could not grab the lock first?

Answer (score 0):

yes, this INFO message is expected and just lets you know that the lock failed (as designed under master/slave shared FS).

To your other question, whichever broker starts first will get the lock, to release it, simply kill the broker and a slave broker should obtain the lock and start...

see this page for more details: http://activemq.apache.org/shared-file-system-master-slave.html